# Random YT Video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want a random yt video playing on my website.
My code looks like this but don't works.

```
<head>
    var vidArr = [
                'HKIW9yRzm04', 'MU8iGMjq1Og', 'WaQ0aFW8YSI', 'DrxJCOVsV1E'
            ]


            var vidID = vidArr[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]

            $("#frame").attr('src', 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidID);
</head>
<iframe id=frame src=" height="100%" with="300px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi Florian, could you give more detail about the problem you're facing and what you've tried so people can better help you? For example, are you getting an exception?

Comment: Hey Brian, I already solved the problem, but thank your for your answer :)

Comment: If your problem is solved, you should accept an answer so that people will know that. Click the check mark on the left side of one of the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several problems here:

1. Your Javascript code needs to be in a `<script>` tag. Simply putting it in the document `<head>` won't work.
2. That code needs to run *after* the `<iframe>` tag exists in the DOM. The `<script>` tag needs to follow the `<iframe>`, or the code needs to be put into an on-load block (`$(function() { … })`).
3. There are multiple syntactical issues in your `<iframe>` tag. The quotation marks are missing on the `id` (harmless but bad practice), there's a missing closing quote on the `src="` attribute, and you've misspelled the `width` attribute as `with`.

Comment: I just forgot the <script> tag here, but I have it in my code. but thank you for the other tip's, they worked :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you check does values returned by varID are correct yt video URL?

Comment: yes they seem to work. but I don't know if it works with jquery